# Is phosphofrucrokinase1 PFK1 found in the liver?

Tags: biochemistry, cellular-respiration, glucose

I am trying to understand glycolysis control. One thing I am stuck on is whether there is PFK1 in the liver, or only PFK2.

Edit: As far as I am aware, there is no pfk2 in muscle cells, only pfk1. This is entirely under allosteric control of ATP/AMP ratio to control the rate of glycolysis compared with gluconeogenesis. In the liver there is pfk2 which ensures that there is hormonal control of the rate of glycolysis. However is there also pfk1 so that there is a rate of glycolysis sufficient for liver cells to survive, irrespective of the hormone signals?

Comment: What research have you done on your own to try and answer this question? A simple Google search using the title of your question will quickly answer it. **Homework questions** and **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on Biology **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. For more information see our [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: I have read quite a lot about this, but Google was not answering my specific question. I will edit my question with the research I have done so far and the specific point of my confusion.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia article on PFK1 that came up at the very top of the Google search I mentioned previously, the very first paragraph in the body of the article answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

PFK2 ([PFKFB2](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/O60825)) doesn't appear to be present in the liver. The two sources I have used agree that PFK1 ([PFKL](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P17858)) is present in the liver. They diverge regarding the levels of expression of PFKL.

This is the expression of the three 6-phosphofructo-1-kinase and one 6-phosphofructo-1-kinase genes according to the [Human proteome map (mass spectrometry).](http://www.humanproteomemap.org/index.php)

[image]

I can't see a huge dynamic range across the proteins in the liver, although the liver specfic gene (PFKL) is the 'winner' there.

The Human protein atlas (immunohistochemistry) is also a useful source for information and it provides a very different answer. Using immunohistochemistry it shows robust signal for [PFKL but](http://www.proteinatlas.org/ENSG00000141959-PFKL/tissue/liver) not for [PFKFB2 in](http://www.proteinatlas.org/ENSG00000123836-PFKFB2/tissue/liver) the liver.